# MFC Compatible GUI in Visual Studio 2019 and xaml

Tags: windows, xaml, mfc

I work with a C++ code base that relies heavily on legacy MFC.  I want to create/improve some of the GUI's and in ancient past I've worked with X-windows, and some Eclipse.  I'm familiar with VS6.0...VS2013/VS2019 resource manager and the Dialog Widgets..but that is all old tech.

I have been doing a survey... I'd really like to do RUST for it's multi-threaded safety, and most GUI's are multi threaded... with at least an event loop, and possibly other monitoring/processing threads.  But RUST GUI's don't look to sweet.

C# has legs for GUI development... but I would have to create complex socket connections as it would be difficult/messy to link a C# application with our existing C++ MFC communication stack code.

I think VS2019 XAML is legs, but it looks like to use it I have to be in .NET newer Windows Runtime stacks, and not older MFC runtime.

Was hoping for a XAML or other Eclipse like GUI stack that could manage the widget placement/resource generation nicely, and also integrate with ancient MFC for a period.
If I have to, I could create my own communications stack... but the older MFC package we use is important for the multi-processor environment this app has to live in.
So I'm actually thinking that possibly using https protocol might work.  Just add a DLL payload that the applications load to add HTTPS communication and then just jettison the MFC libraries and propriatary communication stack and use something general purpose.

Just curious if anyone has XAML GUIs working with MFC out there.

-- Regards

Comment: TL;DR: Don't bother. The sad reality is that MFC is the latest first-party UI framework that has C++ developers covered. WPF was dead on arrival to native developers. *"System XAML"* had a window of opportunity, but Microsoft failed to explain what it is (or even give it an official name), and consequently, the best native UI framework we've had so far never attracted enough native developer interest to cater to them. Today, WinUI is effectively C#-only. C++/WinRT has stopped trying, and Rust's language projection for the Windows Runtime bailed out after just months.

Comment: I also have a large MFC program developed over years. We extended the C++ code with C++/CLI and easily integrated a lot of C# / .Net code. So it shouldn't be a problem to use WinUI from C++/CLI too...

Comment: @xMRi You cannot use WinUI from C++/CLI. WinUI is a native implementation with a native interface that just happens to be accessible from C#, too.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. This seems to be the state of things.  I attempted to build an XAML-ISlands sample from GitHUB which was circa 2020, but this has build issues with VS> 16.8.  Builds in VS16.5.4, but crashes on execution and has some registration issues. Self signed security cert expired in 2022, but likely no factor.  Just seems like "hey we have this good idea" and nobody came.
I just thought I would investiage the "Microsoft Roadmap beyond MFC" a bit.